# Issue with div floating on top of carousel

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/) and there's a weird bug on my page and I can't figure it out! Essentially, I'm trying to overlay a `<div>` on top of my carousel.

When I place the `<div>` on top, this weird gap pops up on top of the carousel! I don't know where it's coming from. Is it in the JavaScript?

The black box, I can format later. Just need to know why the white space is appearing.

**[JsFiddle from the bug](http://jsfiddle.net/wmJn9/)**

### HTML

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
        <div class="jcarousel">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/850/500" width="850" height="500" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/850/500" width="850" height="500" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="http://placekitten.com/850/500" width="850" height="500" alt="">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a>
        <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>
        <p class="jcarousel-pagination"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#login-carousel-wrapper {
    width: 850px;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}
    #login-carousel-area {
    background-color: #000;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
    left: 100px;
}
#body-wrapper {
    width: 970px;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    text-align: top;
}
.carousel-wrapper {
    max-width: 850px;
    /*padding: 0 20px 40px 20px;*/
    margin: auto;
}
.jcarousel-wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    border: 10px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}
.jcarousel-wrapper .photo-credits {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    opacity: .66;
}
.jcarousel-wrapper .photo-credits a {
    color: #fff;
}
/** Carousel **/
 .jcarousel {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 850px;
    height: 500px;
}
.jcarousel ul {
    width: 20000em;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.jcarousel li {
    float: left;
}
/** Carousel Controls **/
     .jcarousel-control-prev, .jcarousel-control-next {
    position: absolute;
    top: 200px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    background: #4E443C;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
    font: 24px/27px Arial, sans-serif;
    -webkit-border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}
.jcarousel-control-prev {
    left: -50px;
}
.jcarousel-control-next {
    right: -50px;
}
.jcarousel-control-prev:hover span, .jcarousel-control-next:hover span {
    display: block;
}
.jcarousel-control-prev.inactive, .jcarousel-control-next.inactive {
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: default;
}
/** Carousel Pagination **/
 .jcarousel-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
}
.jcarousel-pagination a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    min-width: 14px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #4E443C;
    border-radius: 14px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 2px;
    opacity: .75;
}
.jcarousel-pagination a.active {
    background: #4E443C;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Comment: Which div are you talking about and where does that whitespace appear exactly?

Answer (score 0):

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XbaJ9/)

If you are talking about the `20px` white line in the top, that comes from `.jcarousel-wrapper`'s `margin: 20px auto;`.

Just change `20px` to `0px` or add a new line overwriting `margin-top` if you want to keep the bottom margin:

```
.jcarousel-wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```