# Gap above carousel

Tags: javascript, css

I hate to clutter up Stack Overflow, but I can't seem to update my original question here - [Issue with div floating on top of carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20276420/issue-with-div-floating-on-top-of-carousel). The JSFiddle was incorrect.

I'm having some trouble with this:
http://jsfiddle.net/myoozik/U6bV8/

If you take a look at above the carousel, there is a giant gap. This comes as a result of adding the black overlay div on top of the carousel.

Any idea on how to get rid of that gap aka how is it being generated?

**HTML**

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper">
<div id="overlay-div">
    </div>
    <div class="jcarousel-wrapper">
        <div class="jcarousel">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <img src="/_shared/img/img1.jpg" width="850" height="500" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="/_shared/img/img2.jpg" width="850" height="500" alt="">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <img src="/_shared/img/img3.jpg" width="850" height="500" alt="">
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div> <a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-prev">&lsaquo;</a><a href="#" class="jcarousel-control-next">&rsaquo;</a>
        <p class="jcarousel-pagination"></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#overlay-div {
    background-color: #000;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    left: 100px;
    top: 300px;
    z-index: 999;
}

.carousel-wrapper {
    max-width: 850px;
    /*padding: 0 20px 40px 20px;*/
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.jcarousel-wrapper {
    margin: 20px auto;
    position: relative;
    /*border: 10px solid #fff;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
       -moz-border-radius: 5px;
            border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
       -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
            box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;*/
}
.jcarousel-wrapper .photo-credits {
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    bottom: 0;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #fff;
    text-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85);
    opacity: .66;
}
.jcarousel-wrapper .photo-credits a {
    color: #fff;
}
/** Carousel **/
 .jcarousel {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 850px;
    height: 500px;
}
.jcarousel ul {
    width: 20000em;
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.jcarousel li {
    float: left;
}
/** Carousel Controls **/
 .jcarousel-control-prev, .jcarousel-control-next {
position: absolute;
top: 200px;
width: 30px;
height: 30px;
text-align: center;
background: #4E443C;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
text-shadow: 0 0 1px #000;
font: 24px/27px Arial, sans-serif;
-webkit-border-radius: 30px;
-moz-border-radius: 30px;
border-radius: 30px;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
box-shadow: 0 0 2px #999;
}
.jcarousel-control-prev {
    left: -50px;
}
.jcarousel-control-next {
    right: -50px;
}
.jcarousel-control-prev:hover span, .jcarousel-control-next:hover span {
    display: block;
}
.jcarousel-control-prev.inactive, .jcarousel-control-next.inactive {
    opacity: .5;
    cursor: default;
}
/** Carousel Pagination **/
 .jcarousel-pagination {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 15px;
}
.jcarousel-pagination a {
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 11px;
    line-height: 14px;
    min-width: 14px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #4E443C;
    border-radius: 14px;
    padding: 3px;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 2px;
    opacity: .75;
}
.jcarousel-pagination a.active {
    background: #4E443C;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 1;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The black color box is appearing due to `#overlay-div` Div that is present which has some height, width and background color. if you set `display:none` to it the space and black box will disappear.

below is the `CSS`

```
#overlay-div {
    background-color: #000000;
    display: none;
    height: 200px;
    left: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kishori/8XMh5/) here.

Is this what you are looking at?

Comment: The black box is supposed to be there. I'm concerned about the big gap above the carousel itself. The gap only appears if you display the black box, but I need the black box to float on top. Thanks!

Comment: the space is caused due to position:relative and top:300px; If you use position:absolute and margin-top, then it would remove the giant space.

Comment: The CSS is something like this #overlay-div {
    background-color: #000000;
    display: block;
    height: 200px;
    left: 304px;
    margin-top: 154px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    z-index: 999;
}

Comment: Incredible! Thank you so much. Can you elaborate on the behaviour of the black box div and why absolute is better than relative in this case?

Comment: using display:relative will place the Div in relative position with other div with same hierarchy. So in our case, black box had some top value which was moving it downwards and hence it was pushing the next Div.